# Are application specific scripting languages on topic on this site?

Tags: discussion

Are application specific questions on topic at this site? I am an auditor and would love some feedback about an ACL script I wrote a while ago.
ACL is short for [Audit Command Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL_(software_company)).

Comment: So, you want to ask what as a question there? Feels like you want to post your script and get comments on it. That is off topic because we don't do code review, no matter the language.

Comment: Is this roughly the same as Autodesk's [tag:maya] (using either their own language MEL or Python), Microsoft's [tag:VBA], and Adobe's [tag:extendscript] support for their suite of graphics applications?

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was CodeReview.... Wrong Site

Answer (score 1):

If it's a programming language, it's fine to ask questions on SO about problems you encounter while using that language. Note that being on-topic does not in any way guarantee answers - there could be better places to ask coding questions in very specialized languages.

If you already have working code in such language and are looking for feedback -- [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the right site.

A reasonable indication for a language being on-topic is the presence of language tag with recent positively scored questions. Again, if you don't see one, there is very good chance that you will not be able to get useful feedback due to a lack of experts for that language on the site.

Comment: Alexi - I've broadened the scope of languages in the first sentence. Being Turing complete isn't a requirement for a programming language to be on-topic for this site -- for example: HTML, SQL, and regular expressions are not Turing complete, but are still generally considered on-topic.